# Required attribute 'duplicateFilePattern' not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, server-error, elfinder

I'm using elFinder Webfroms version from https://elfinder.codeplex.com/. I've downloaded and tried to run the project but unable to run the project. I'm getting following error while running the test project.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Required attribute 'duplicateFilePattern' not
>   found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 12:    Line 13:  Line 14:   
>   defaultVolumeName="LocalFileSystem"
>   baseUrl="http://localhost:56439/data/"
>   baseThumbsUrl="http://localhost:56439/data/.thumbs/"> Line 16:
>
> Source File:
>   C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\elFinderFileManager\elFinderFileManager\web.config
>   Line: 14
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

Error:
[image]

I've tried a lot to find on Google to find out the reason for this error but was not able to find any single clue on the web.

Please anyone know about it, let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure, as I can't find the docs easily, but the error is saying that you must specify a value for the duplicateFilePattern property.

A quick search on SO finds a common value for this is

```
duplicateFilePattern="Copy of {0}"
```

suggesting it's a format string used to alter the name of a file in case it already exists.

I'd suggest checking your documentation for elFinder, specifically the section on configurations.

Comment: you're genius!, thanks. :)

I've even checked and get idea from https://elfinder.codeplex.com/discussions/473624 this thread.